# How do I combine three lists in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, datatable

I want to combine three lists, my lists:

```dart
var px = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
var x = [0, 1, 2];
var mutiply = [0, 0.2, 0.6];
```

How can I combine these three lists? I want to retrieve all the list data into a table with ListView.

I want to represent the data like this:

[image: Example Image Attached for Final input]

Please guide me how to do it! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataTable` for this case.

[image]

You can config others properties.

```dart
 DataTable(
            headingRowColor:
                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(.5)),
            showBottomBorder: true,
            columns: const [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("x"),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("p(x)"),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("x*p(x)"),
              ),
            ],
            rows: [
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text(x[0].toString())),
                DataCell(Text(px[0].toString())),
                DataCell(Text(mutiply[0].toStringAsFixed(3))),
              ]),
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text(x[1].toString())),
                DataCell(Text(px[1].toString())),
                DataCell(Text(mutiply[1].toStringAsFixed(3))),
              ]),
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text(x[2].toString())),
                DataCell(Text(px[2].toString())),
                DataCell(Text(mutiply[2].toStringAsFixed(3))),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Can you help me, please !! if Length of Lists is from Users Input then how I retrieve data into the table , help me Brother

Comment: Depends on scenario, you can use map/generate functionality for that. The fact is values depend on rows , like `x=  [0,1,2]` will be constructed as row instead of column, you can also create/looks for separate question on dynamic DataTable based on user input.

Comment: If you need help feel free to ask.

Comment: can I contact you privately?

Comment: I posted a new question please check